# After appending cells, find min and max of five different categories in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, max, min

Hello everyone I have a question. I just now learning min and max.

I'm having trouble in finding the min and max of five columns for each category

Heres what I have:

I moved a 5 columns of 26 column data from a csv file to a txt file.

for example
the appended cells for .csv are like

```
state          car      motorcycle   van        airplane       bike 
Maine          35.5      8.1         5.7         21.0%         33.2%
Michigan       47.9      9.1         5.5         20.40%        25.2%                   
Washington     52.5      1.2         4.6          3.50%        24.7%                     
Denver         21.8      20.5        5.3          2.90%        30.9%
```

how do I get the min and max to look like this

```
                   min                       max
car             Denver:      21.8          Washington: 52.5   
motor           Washington:  1.2           Denver:     20.5 
van             Washington   4.6           Maine:       5.7 
airplane        Denver       2.90%         Maine       21.0% 
bike            Washington   24.7%         Maine      33.2%                    -
```

Here is what I have

```
import csv
import string, re
import operator

output = []
data = []
csv_string = []
data_file = []

try:
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_string:
         for line in csv_string:
             cells = line.split(",")
             output.append((cells[0], cells[1], cells[5], cells[7], cells[11], cells[13]))
                         for lines in output:


            #state = cells[0]

            zmin = cells[1]   #car = cells[1]
            ymin = cells[1]
            xmin = cells[5]   #motor = cells[5] 
            wmin = cells[5]
            vmin = cells[7]   #van = cells[7]
            zmax = cells[7]
            ymax = cells[11]  #airplane = cells[11]
            xmax = cells[11]
            wmax = cells[13]  #bike = cells[13] 
            vmax = cells[13]

        if cells[1] < xmin: 
            zmin = cells[1] 
        if cells[1] > xmax: 
            zmax = cells[1]


        if cells[5] < ymin: 
            ymin = cells[5]
        if cells[5] > ymax: 
            ymax = cells[5]

        if cells[7] < zmin:
            xmin = cells[7]
        if cells[7] > zmax: 
            xmax = cells[7] 

        if cells[11] < zmin:
            wmin = cells[11]
        if cells[11] > zmax: 
            wmax = cells[11]

        if cells[13] < zmin:
            vmin = cells[13]
        if cells[13] > zmax: 
            vmax = cells[13]

        outstring = ' '
    for item in output:
            for cell in item:
                outstring += "{0:<35}".format(cell) #Width/Distance of each row
            outstring += "\n"

    print(outstring)

    print('Min: ',zmin,ymin,xmin,wmin,vmin)

    print('Max: ',state,zmax,ymax,xmax,wmax,vmax) 


  finally:
          f.close()

try:    
    f_write = open('output.txt', 'w') #creates the file
    try:
        f_write.writelines(outstring)

  finally:
          f.close()
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I been reading min and max but I don't understand how this applies in a .csv file while appending 5 columns.

If anyone can offer some guidance, Thank you for your input.

The program prints wrong numbers

```
 print('Min: ',zmin,ymin,xmin,wmin,vmin)
      47.9,  8.1, 5.5, 20.40%, 25.2% 
 print('Max: ',state,zmax,ymax,xmax,wmax,vmax) 
      21.8, 9.1, 4.6, 20.40%, 30.9%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do much of what is needed by using Python's built-in `csv` module. Here's how to find the minimum and maximum values of a list of fields (or columns) of the data. The contents of sample `data.csv` file shown only has the fields of interest in it, but could contain all 26 columns of data without affecting the code which only processes the fields who's names appear in the `FIELDS` list.

```
import csv

ID = 'state'
FIELDS = ['car', 'motorcycle', 'van', 'airplane', 'bike']
MIN_ID, MIN, MAX_ID, MAX = 0, 1, 2, 3  # indices of data in min_maxes records

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    # initialize min and max values from first row of csv file
    row = csv_dict_reader.next()
    min_maxes = {field: [row[ID], float(row[field])]*2 for field in FIELDS}

    # update min and max values with data from remaining rows of csv file
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        for id, value, min_max_rec in (
                (row[ID], float(row[field]), min_maxes[field]) for field in FIELDS):
            if value < min_max_rec[MIN]:
                min_max_rec[MIN_ID] = id
                min_max_rec[MIN]    = value
            if value > min_max_rec[MAX]:
                min_max_rec[MAX_ID] = id
                min_max_rec[MAX]    = value

print '                   min                  max'
for field in FIELDS:
    min_max_rec = min_maxes[field]
    print '{:10}    {:12}{:4.1f}      {:12}{:4.1f}'.format(field,
              min_max_rec[MIN_ID]+':', min_max_rec[MIN],
              min_max_rec[MAX_ID]+':', min_max_rec[MAX])
```

Input (simplified `data.csv` file):

```
state,car,motorcycle,van,airplane,bike
Maine,35.5,8.1,5.7,21.0,33.2
Michigan,47.9,9.1,5.5,20.40,25.2
Washington,52.5,1.2,4.6,3.,24.7
Denver,21.8,20.5,5.3,2.90,30.9
```

Output:

```
                   min                  max
car           Denver:     21.8      Washington: 52.5
motorcycle    Washington:  1.2      Denver:     20.5
van           Washington:  4.6      Maine:       5.7
airplane      Denver:      2.9      Maine:      21.0
bike          Washington: 24.7      Maine:      33.2
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear I'm trying to get the min and the max of each category in the csv file. then write the data into another file.

Comment: @ThomasJones: To output the min and max data to another file, just write the contents of the `min_maxes` dictionary to it formatted in whatever way is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - a library designed for such data manipulation, the task becomes a lot simpler:

```
import pandas as pd

c = lambda x: float(x.strip('%'))
df = pd.read_csv(f,sep='\s+', converters = {'bike':c, 'airplane':c})

vehicles = df.columns[1:]  #['car', 'motorcycle', 'van', 'airplane', 'bike']

max_v = zip(df['state'][df[vehicles].idxmax().values], 
            df[vehicles].max().values.astype('|S4'))
min_v = zip(df['state'][df[vehicles].idxmin().values],
            df[vehicles].min().values.astype('|S4'))

max_i = [': '.join(tup) for tup in max_v]
min_i = [': '.join(tup) for tup in min_v]

print pd.DataFrame({'min':min_i, 'max':max_i}, index=vehicles)
```

out:

```
                         max               min
car         Washington: 52.5      Denver: 21.8
motorcycle      Denver: 20.5   Washington: 1.2
van               Maine: 5.7   Washington: 4.6
airplane         Maine: 21.0       Denver: 2.9
bike             Maine: 33.2  Washington: 24.7
```